# Ktor - Create Multiple Subdomains Programatically

Tags: kotlin, backend, ktor

Okay so this may sound like a stupid question, but I really need to know, is there a way to create multiple domains programatically with Ktor. For example, let's say that I have a domain: **example.com**

Now I need the logic on my backend server to create a new subdomain for each user that register on my website. For example, when John register, I want to immediately be able to create a new subdomain: **john.example.com** . Now I'm not sure what and how this can be achieved, that's why I'm asking here for some directions?

And if that's too complex, then is there a way to create multiple endpoints dynamically from the code, after each and every user registration on my website, like: **example.com/John** ?

Is there any good resource that I can read about that?

Comment: I don't know ktor, but subdomains would require either adding DNS entries programmatically to your name servers, or configuring your name server to automatically return CNAME entries for any unrecognized domain. It's possible, but probably not something that's worth the trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Ktor side, you can add routes dynamically after the server startup and use the `host` route builder to match the requested host. Additionally, you need to add DNS entries programmatically as @Stephen Jennings said. Here's an example where after 5 seconds the route for the host `john.example.com` is added. You can test it locally with the entry `127.0.0.1    john.example.com`  in the `/etc/hosts` file.

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 4444) {
        routing {
            get("/example") {
                call.respondText { "example" }
            }
        }
    }

    server.start(wait = false)

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        delay(5000)
        val routing = server.application.feature(Routing)
        routing.addRoutesForHost("john.example.com")
    }
}

fun Route.addRoutesForHost(host: String) {
    host(host) {
        get("/hello") {
            call.respondText { "Hello ${call.request.headers[HttpHeaders.Host]}" }
        }
    }
}
```